# How to increase timeout when calling webservice in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, settimeout, timeoutexception

I am developed one windows phone app.but app was crashed due to timeout exception.how to handle this timeout exception.please help me.below is my code:

```
  public async void Login()
        {


     var client = new NewReloadApp.JsonWebClient();

      var resp = await client.DoRequestAsync(Url.weburl + "Validateuser_v2?Emailid=" + Emailid.Text + "&Password=" + password.Password + "&DeviceID=" + deviceid + "&PlatformID=7&DeviceToken=windowsReload&Mobilemodel=nokia&Appversion=1.4.14&MobileOS=windows");

                string result = resp.ReadToEnd();

                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(result);
}
```

I am not using any httpwebrequest method.in the above code I try to set timeout property but I could not get any timeout method.please help me how to set timeout for the above code.

below is my jsonwebclient class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NewReloadApp
{
    class JsonWebClient
    {

        public async Task<T> DoRequestJsonAsync<T>(WebRequest req)
        {
            var ret = await DoRequestAsync(req);
            var response = await ret.ReadToEndAsync();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
        }

        public async Task<T> DoRequestJsonAsync<T>(string uri)
        {
            var ret = await DoRequestAsync(uri);
            var response = await ret.ReadToEndAsync();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
        }

        public async Task<System.IO.TextReader> DoRequestAsync(WebRequest req)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync((cb, o) => ((HttpWebRequest)o).BeginGetResponse(cb, o), res => ((HttpWebRequest)res.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(res), req);
            var result = await task;
            var resp = result;
            var stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
            return sr;
        }

        public async Task<System.IO.TextReader> DoRequestAsync(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            req.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
            var tr = await DoRequestAsync(req);
            return tr;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you will probably have to share the jsonwebclient class, or link to it (at least im not familiar with it)

Comment: @zedd please see my edited code I am sharing my jsonwebclient class

Comment: public async Task<System.IO.TextReader> DoRequestAsync(string url)
        {
            
            HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            req.ContinueTimeout = 30000;
            req.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
            var tr = await DoRequestAsync(req);
            return tr;
        }

Comment: @zedd I am added  req.ContinueTimeout = 30000 in the above code  is it correct or not to extened timeout value

Answer (score 1):

> Use a CancellationToken:

I dint try but it may help you.

```
public async Task<System.IO.TextReader> DoRequestAsync(string url)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource ct= new CancellationTokenSource(2000); //2 
        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        req.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
        var tr = await DoRequestAsync(req).AsTask(ct.Token);;
        return tr;
    }
```

as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060575/how-to-set-time-out-for-http-client-request-operation-in-windows-phone-8-1-windo)

Comment: thank you for your response but its not working for me.

Comment: Iam using .ContinueTimeout method is it correct or not.please help me

Comment: you can try _req.timeout_